# Can we migrate local beanstalkd to GCP Compute instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, beanstalkd

I have local system that have a beanstalkd application running.Now i want to migrate to GCP compute instances.

I have installed beanstalkd on CE.So how i can migrate this to CE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are straightworfard

1. make sure binlog is activated
2. locate the binlog file
3. stop the Beanstalkd instance, for fully graceful shutdown, so binlog file should be flushed
4. upload to Cloud Storage, (either using the Console or using gcloud utility)
5. on the Compute Engine instance, make sure you have Storage permission in the edit section
6. download using gcloud commands the binlog file to the machine itself
7. start the beanstalkd service and woala, your persisted messages are there

you can setup on the same machine or other machines [Beanstalkd Console Admin](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console)